# routines, channels and infinite loops

Tags: go

I am trying to get information from channel, but looks like my code isn`t running after go routinnes. 
Both my routines are working and first one collects info, and last one is watching for filling, and if filling is ends second routine stops both routines
how i can get information and get running code after routines? Or perhaps is there any right way to get info?

```
func main() {
    watcher, _ := winlog.NewWinLogWatcher()
    watcher.SubscribeFromBeginning("Application", `*`)
    i := 0
    c := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            if flag == true {
                return
            }
            select {
            case evt := <-watcher.Event():
                i+=1
                var event Event
                data := []byte(evt.Xml)
                _ = xml.Unmarshal(data, &event)
                Events = append(Events, event)
            case err := <-watcher.Error():
                break
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            if flag == true {
                break
            }
            if I == 0 || I != i {
                I = i
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
            if i == I && flag == false{
                flag = true
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
        }
    }()
    <-c
    // *** i cant print this info ***
    time.Sleep(10*time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println(`Events counter:`, len(Events))
}
```

Comment: Nobody is sending anything or closing the channel `c`, so `<-c` is a blocking forever operation. If you want the code after that to be executed, remove that operation. If you need to wait for the goroutines, close the channel when they're done or use `sync.WaitGroup`. What is it exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Read from channel `<-c` is blocking operation.

Since you are not writing to this channel, you block further actions after reading from the channel.

You can use sync.WaitGroup

```
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(1)
go func () {
    defer wg.Done()
    ...
}
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: yes, this solution works me,  @icza have sent it. All i read before in howto`s is not obviously for my question. Thank you